# How access Drivers folder in minifilter driver

Tags: c, driver, minifilter

My minifilter driver start type is on a boot, I wont to access to `c:\windows\system32\drivers` folder in `InstanceSetup` callback, I tried `\SystemRoot\system32\drivers` and I got `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, but when I tried `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\windows\system32\drivers` it worked.

My question is can I be sure that `HarddiskVolume2` path will always have the drive that the current operating system is installed? Maybe I should use sometimes `HarddiskVolume3` or `HarddiskVolume4`, How can I know it?

Comment: HarddiskVolumeX this is not permanent name. it can be point to any partition, depended from disks configuration. so you of course can not be sure. but are you tried `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\windows\system32\drivers` at same time as `\SystemRoot\system32\drivers` ? you sure ?

Comment: @RbMm Yes, when `HarddiskVolume2` works `SystemRoot` not works, and when `SystemRoot` works `HarddiskVolume2` not works.

Comment: strange. usual it must both work or not work at same time. at early boot time must not work(both) and then later begin work(both)